# Not displaying anchor tag value

Tags: html

The below code doesn't work!!! 
My scenario: i want to get,if user clicks on the B,then i will throw the popup with clicked value..For instance,He clicks on A link,then i need to throw the popup with value you clicked'A'
Constraints:i shouldn't call the function getcontent in each tag... i should call in div itself....Kindly help me in this..

Thanks in advance..:-)

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function GetContent() {
                alert('hi');
                var outerDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML;
                var h = outerDiv.getElementsByTagName("a").getElementsByClassName('anchr').innetHTMLalert(h);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="myDiv" onclick='GetContent()'><a id="anchr" href="www.google.com">A</a>

<a class="anchr" href="javascript:openAlert();">P</a>
            <a
            class="anchr" href="www.google.com">B</a><a class="anchr" href="www.google.com">Q</a>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `getElementsByTagName` returns a *NodeList* not an *Element*. Elements have a `getElementsByClassName` method, NodeLists do not. You need to loop over the NodeList (it is similar to an Array) and deal with each Element it holds in turn.
2. `getElementsByClassName` also returns a *NodeList*. Elements have an `innerHTML` property, NodeLists do not. Again, loop.
3. `innerHTML` doesn't have a `t` in it
4. You need a `;` between `innerHTML` and your next statement (`alert(h)`).

---

> i shouldn't call the function getcontent in each tag. i should call in div itself

1. Stop using intrinsic event attributes (`onclick` and friends)
2. Start using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)
3. Capture the event object by accepting an argument in the function you pass there
4. Examine the `target` property of that object

Such:

```
function getContent(evt) {  // Don't start function names with capital letters unless they are Constructor functions
    var element = evt.target;
    alert(element.innerHTML);
    evt.preventDefault();
}
div.addEventListener("click", getContent);
```

Comment: THis line div.addEventListener("click", getContent); inside script tag ?

Comment: Yes, JavaScript goes inside script elements (or in an external JS file referenced by a `src` attribute).

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> function getContent(evt) { var element = evt.target; alert(element.innerHTML); evt.preventDefault(); } div.addEventListener("click", getContent); </script> </head> <body> <div> <a class="anchr" href="www.google.com">A</a> <a class="anchr" href="www.google.com">P</a> </div> </body> </html> not working !!! sorry

Comment: You haven't assigned a value to `div` and even if you had, you are trying to bind the event handler to it before it exists.

Comment: nope..i don't want div values..i need to get anchor tag value which is inside div tag..on clicking anyone of the links,the function should be called.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> function getContent(evt) { var element = evt.target; alert(element.innerHTML); evt.preventDefault(); } div.addEventListener("click", getContent); </script> is this correct?

Comment: <div id="mydiv"> <a class="anchr" href="#">A</a> <a class="anchr" href="#">P</a> <a class="anchr" href="#">B</a> </div> is this correct?

Comment: can u check it and tell me

Comment: Quentin any idea? can u test and if it is working fine,then post it pls

Comment: You still have to assign a value to `div`.

Comment: may i know how to assign?

Comment: You really need to read an introductory JavaScript tutorial (one which focuses on client side work and includes DOM, which is practically all of them). `var div = document.getElementBySomeId('a div');`

Comment: getting error in this line var div = document.getElementBySomeId('a div');

Comment: i fixed the above issue ..now getting Error: 'div' is null or not an object

Comment: @Quetin getting null exceptio

Comment: Yes ran it ...getting above exception

Comment: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8)
Timestamp: Sun, 1 Sep 2013 19:28:05 UTC

Message: 'div' is null or not an object
URI: file:///C:/Users/303872/Desktop/test.htm

Comment: What did you change from the code you posted in the 4th comment on this answer in order to make it run after the div existed?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> function getcontent() { // Don't start function names with capital letters unless they are Constructor functions alert('hi'); var element = evt.target; alert(element.innerHTML); evt.preventDefault(); } var div = document.getElementById('mydiv'); div.addEventListener("click", getContent); </script>

Comment: please check the updated code which ws placed in above comment

Comment: There's nothing in the latest version of the code you pasted which would delay the running of it until the div was created. Did you do something else to delay the running of it until then?